# Is there any formula to find cell reference from search function in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, search

I have a range in column AH:AH19,

```
OXFORD
MOSBY
CELL
AMER
BLACKWELL
```

I want to use search function in column AI. It returns the value as true or false to column AJ when find something.
Column AI contains for example

```
BLACKWELL PUBL LTD
ISRAEL MEDICAL ASSOC JOURNAL
PERGAMON-ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD 
PERGAMON-ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD
MOSBY, INC
OXFORD UNIV PRESS
CELL PRESS
AMER COLL PHYSICIANS
```

So for example, each time the words OXFORD, MOBSY, CELL, AMER, BLACKWELL etc. any of one needed to  search/find in column AI and returns the value in cell AJ as TRUE or FALSE.

I have build the formula for this as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AH$15:$AH$22,AI15)))>0
```

But they do not seem to work. If any suggestions please help to find TRUE and FALSE value as well which value of column AH matching with AI is required.

Example of wanted result

```
OXFORD  BLACKWELL PUBL LTD  TRUE    BLACKWELL

MOSBY   ISRAEL MEDICAL ASSOC JOURNAL    TRUE    FALSE

CELL    PERGAMON-ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD   TRUE    FALSE

AMER    PERGAMON-ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD   TRUE    FALSE

BLACKWELL   MOSBY, INC  TRUE    MOBSY

    OXFORD UNIV PRESS   TRUE    OXFORD

    CELL PRESS  TRUE    CELL

    AMER COLL PHYSICIANS    TRUE    AMER
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvano.jpg)

I want to be find the values of AK using formula/function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVbTA.jpg)

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jsTf2fS7dByLZNflFpxVYouy7-5F3HTE0FHMdRY75Pg/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(B4:B,lambda(Σ,iferror(+tocol(index(if(search(A4:A,Σ),A4:A)),3))))
```

[image]